# JS Chart: do not merge duplicate x axis labels

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to display a spline area chart using JSCharting (but the method is not important for me, any working solution is ok), with alphabetical letters as X Axis labels (I work with amino acids of proteins, this is the reason why letters).
So I want to show all values for each letter, even if there are duplicates.
For exemple:

```
{x: "V", y: 0.72}
{x: "A", y: 0.59}
{x: "F", y: 0.59}
{x: "T", y: 0.65}
{x: "E", y: 0.59}
{x: "K", y: 0.63}
{x: "Q", y: 0.67}
{x: "D", y: 0.6}
{x: "A", y: 0.58}
{x: "L", y: 0.7}
{x: "V", y: 0.77}
{x: "S", y: 0.54}
{x: "S", y: 0.53}
{x: "S", y: 0.67}
{x: "F", y: 0.69}
{x: "E", y: 0.54}
{x: "A", y: 0.5}
{x: "F", y: 0.52}
{x: "K", y: 0.71}
{x: "A", y: 0.84}
{x: "N", y: 0.89}
{x: "I", y: 0.91}
```

Displays:
[image]

It is a mess and makes no sense.
What I want is to see all points individually and sequentially because this is how it makes sense, not merged. All of the X axis labels should be displayed.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Such data is typically rendered in a [scatter](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html) chart. I believe however that `x` and `y` values of your data points need to be of number format. Therefore you need to process your `data` prior to use it in your chart.

Then you must define a [`xAxes.ticks.callback`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) function and a [`tooltips.callbacks.label`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) function in order to render the original data.

Please have a look at the runnable code snippet below.

```js
const data = [
  {x: "V", y: 0.72},
  {x: "A", y: 0.59},
  {x: "F", y: 0.59},
  {x: "T", y: 0.65},
  {x: "E", y: 0.59},
  {x: "K", y: 0.63},
  {x: "Q", y: 0.67},
  {x: "D", y: 0.6},
  {x: "A", y: 0.58},
  {x: "L", y: 0.7},
  {x: "V", y: 0.77},
  {x: "S", y: 0.54},
  {x: "S", y: 0.53},
  {x: "S", y: 0.67},
  {x: "F", y: 0.69},
  {x: "E", y: 0.54},
  {x: "A", y: 0.5},
  {x: "F", y: 0.52},
  {x: "K", y: 0.71},
  {x: "A", y: 0.84},
  {x: "N", y: 0.89},
  {x: "I", y: 0.91}
];
const xLabels = data.reduce((acc, v) => acc.includes(v.x) ? acc : acc.concat(v.x), []).sort();

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      borderColor: 'green',
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
      data: data.map(o => ({ x: xLabels.indexOf(o.x), y: o.y }))
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        offset: true,
        ticks: {          
          stepSize: 1,
          callback: v => xLabels[v]
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (tooltipItem, data) => xLabels[tooltipItem.xLabel] + ': ' + tooltipItem.value
      }
    }  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that it's been a long time since the question was posted and there've been a lot of changes in chart.js in the meanwhile, but this was post I was sent to by google, while having the same issue.

So, with chart.js 4.1.2, a solution to get rid of the merged duplicate labels is to explicitly set the `labels` properties of the data. I suppose that's the way it is done by most from the get go. Still, if you don't set `data.labels`, but get the labels from the dataset(s) (as `x` property or through `parsing.xAxisKey`) option, you'll get the merging feature.

The OP case without merging ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqgkdusx/))

```js
const data = [
    {x: "V", y: 0.72},
    {x: "A", y: 0.59},
    {x: "F", y: 0.59},
    {x: "T", y: 0.65},
    {x: "E", y: 0.59},
    {x: "K", y: 0.63},
    {x: "Q", y: 0.67},
    {x: "D", y: 0.6},
    {x: "A", y: 0.58},
    {x: "L", y: 0.7},
    {x: "V", y: 0.77},
    {x: "S", y: 0.54},
    {x: "S", y: 0.53},
    {x: "S", y: 0.67},
    {x: "F", y: 0.69},
    {x: "E", y: 0.54},
    {x: "A", y: 0.5},
    {x: "F", y: 0.52},
    {x: "K", y: 0.71},
    {x: "A", y: 0.84},
    {x: "N", y: 0.89},
    {x: "I", y: 0.91}
];

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    
    data: {
        labels: data.map(o=>o.x),
        datasets:[{
            data: data.map(o=>o.y)
        }]
    },
    
    options: {
        fill: true,
        plugins:{
            legend:{
                display: false
            }
        }
    }
};

new Chart(document.querySelector('#line-chart'), config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.2/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-t41WshQCxr9T3SWH3DBZoDnAT9gfVLtQS+NKO60fdAwScoB37rXtdxT/oKe986G0BFnP4mtGzXxuYpHrMoMJLA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div id="line-chart-container" style="height:300px">
<canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

And in case that's just you always did it and are wondering if the merging is still happening, yes it is - just delete `data.labels` and set `data.datasets:[{data}]` - see [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqgkdusx/1/). This actually is a very useful and natural feature, if the identical labels are consecutive - it just stacks vertically the different `y` values that correspond to the same `x` instead of spreading them horizontally. Still, if there is (or *when* there will be) a simple option to disable this feature, this is a good place to let us know.