# How remove duplicates xAxis labels and show all values on chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

How i can remove all label duplicates

[image: example img]

if i remove duplicates by spread operator

```
labelsNonUnique = [29.03,30.03,30.03,30.03,30.03,30.03,30.03,31.03,31.03,31.03,01.04,01.04,01.04,01.04,01.04,01.04,02.04];
labels = [...new Set(labelsNonUnique)];
```

all duplicates been removed, but value points on chart been deleted too

[image: example img]

How to remove duplicate labels without deleting points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `data` values have not really been deleted but you can only see the first n values. Their number corresponds to the number of left over `labels`. Also the values do now no longer match the correct `labels`. Remember that the number of `labels` must be the same as the number of `data` values.

Technically, when removing duplicate labels, you'll end up having multiple y values at the same x coordinate. If this is what you want, you better convert the `line` chart into a `scatter` chart (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63085003/2358409)).

An other option would be to sum up values at the same x coordinate, same as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66929487/2358409).

Again another option would be to define a `ticks.callback` function on the x-axis that would make sure to return identical `labels` only once and `null` otherwise (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63913674/2358409) given to a similar question).

Comment: thanks, it certainly didn't solve the problem. But now I realized that there is a dependence of the number of labels and values.